# GCC #pragma or command options

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, pragma

If the compiler has some command-line flags and the code has some pragmas that are incompatible with those flags, which one will be used?

To be clearer: I am compiling with `g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++17 -static {files}` – GCC version g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0.

If I write in my code `#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")`, will the final code be compiled with `-O2` or with `-Ofast`?

Comment: That pragma will be local to the current [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) only, it will not affect any other translation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on if it's above or below the pragma.

```
void this_will_be_compiled_with_O2() { stuff(); }

#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")

void this_will_be_compiled_with_Ofast() { stuff(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not *explicitly* mentioned in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html), the description of the `#pragma GCC reset_options` directive *implies* that any `#pragma GCC optimize` directive will override the command line option(s):

> `#pragma GCC reset_options`
>     This pragma clears the current `#pragma GCC target` and `#pragma GCC optimize` to use the default switches as specified on the command line.